# Move $http call with $modal to a service in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, deferred

I have a bunch of repeating code in one of my modules and I'm very confused on the best way to get this out of all of my controllers.  I have a service that manages a list of user profiles.  These are stored in the sessionStorage locally, but if it's empty the service makes a $http call to the API and then caches the results.  The user could enter one of several different pages, so I need to ensure the data is loaded before displaying the screen.  I use $modal to pop-up a box saying that it's loading the profile while the profile services does it's think.  If it's in sessionStorage, it's a blink; if it has to make the API call, it sits for a few seconds while it does so.

Here is the repeating code in my controllers:

```
var modal = $modal.open({ templateUrl: 'template/modal/loadingProfile.html' });
  profileService.getUserBySequence($routeParams.sequence).then(function (data) {
    $scope.user = data;
    profileService.getProfileForUser($scope.user.Sequence).then(function (data) {
      var stop = $timeout(function () {
      if (modal.opened) {
        modal.close();
        $timeout.cancel(stop);
      }
    }, 100);
    $scope.profile = data;
  });
});
```

That's not very pleasant to have at the top of every controller.  Here's a look at the profile service:

```
function getUserBySequence(sequence) {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    getUserList().then(function (data) {
        defer.resolve(data['_' + sequence]);
    }, function(result) {
        alertService.show(result.data.flash);
        defer.reject();
    });
    return defer.promise;
}

function getUserProfile(sequence) {
 var defer = $q.defer();
 var profile = sessionService.get('profile.' + sequence, true);
 if (profile) {
    defer.resolve(profile);
 } else {
    var companyId = sessionService.get('companyId');
    $http.get("http://domain.com/api/getProfile?id=" + companyId + "&sequence=" + sequence).then(function (result) {

       // only parse if a string
       if (typeof result.data == "string") {
          profile = JSON.parse(result.data);
       } else {
          profile = result.data;
       }

       sessionService.set('profile.' + sequence, profile, true);
       defer.resolve(profile);
    }, function (result) {
       sessionService.unset('profile.' + sequence);
       alertService.show(result.data.flash);
       defer.reject();
    });
 }
 return defer.promise;
}
```

What is the best way to get the controller cleaned up?

Comment: move it to a directive and use a watch for custom event to open modal

Comment: How would you use that directive?